# Using recursion to multiplying a sequence of numbers without local variables

Tags: java, recursion

This was a question on a past exam that had my fellow students and me stumped:

> Use recursion to multiply together every number in a series without using local variables. Assume:
>
> - the parameters are positive
> - the first parameter is less than the second parameter
> - the result is less than 2<sup>31</sup>

For example, `rangeProduct(1, 5)` should return `120`, because 1x2x3x4x5 is 120

Use this method signature:

```
public static int rangeProduct(int valueOne, int valueTwo) {
    return ?;
}
```

If anyone knows how to do this, it's simply to benefit my learning and, if you're looking for some practice or simply feel empathy for a starving, moderately knowledgeable Computer Science major, then take a swing!

Comment: Write a normal recursive factorial function, return fact(valueTwo)/fact(valueOne-1).

Comment: @azurefrog - That seems like a lot of extra work to compute rangeProduct(1000006,1000007 ). :)

Comment: @AndyThomas I was a math major, so I naturally phrase all my answers in terms of previously solved problems... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public static int rangeProduct(int valueOne, int valueTwo) {
  if(valueOne>=valueTwo)
    return valueOne;
  return rangeProduct(valueOne, valueTwo-1) * valueTwo;
}
```

executes the calculation in the exact order you specified:

```
1x2=2, 2x3=6, 6x4=24, 24x5=120
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a solution to your problem:

```
public static int rangeProduct(int valueOne, int valueTwo)
{
    if(valueOne <= valueTwo -1){
        valueOne++;
        return (valueOne-1) * rangeProduct(valueOne, valueTwo);
    }
    return valueTwo;
}
```

Comment: Try not to increment the local variable with ++ but pass an incremented value to the recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int rangeProduct(int valueOne, int valueTwo)
{
    // to avoid infinite loop if valueOne must be less or equal valueTwo
    if (valueOne > valueTwo) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    // terminal case : return one over two values
    if (valueOne == valueTwo) {
        return valueOne;
    }
    // recursive call with range's size decreasing
    return valueOne * rangeProduct(valueOne+1, valueTwo);
}
```

To reduce the number of recursive calls the size can be decreased one both sides

```
public static int rangeProduct(int valueOne, int valueTwo)
{
    if (valueOne > valueTwo) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    if (valueOne == valueTwo) {
        return valueOne;
    } else if (valueOne == valueTwo-1) {
        return valueOne*valueTwo;
    }
    return valueOne*valueTwo * rangeProduct(valueOne+1, valueTwo-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That should not be hard at all.

Let's do this iteratively first to understand how this should work.

```
    public static int rangeProduct(int valueOne, int valueTwo)
    {
      int prod = 1;

      for(int i = valueOne; i <= valueTwo; i++) {
          prod *= i;
      }

      return prod;

    }
```

So doing this recursively would be just as simple:

```
    public static int rangeProduct(int valueOne, int valueTwo)
    {
        if (valueOne ==0 || valueTwo == 0) return 0;

        //Range check
        if (valueOne > valueTwo) return rangeProduct(valueTwo, valueOne);

        if (valueOne < 0 && valueTwo > 0) return 0; //Because 0 is always in this range

        if (valueOne == valueTwo) return valueTwo;  

        return valueTwo*rangeProd(valueOne, valueTwo-1);
    }
```

**Logic used for recursion**: Say you have a range (3,5) then : 
 
(3,5) = 5*(3,4) = 5*4*(3,3) = 5*4*3 = 60 
(-3, -1) = -1*(-3, -2) = -1*-2*(-3,-3) = -6 
(-3, 5) = 0 (because this range includes 0) 
(5, 3) is same as (3,5) so this can return 60 as well. 
(3 ,3) --> now if both no's are same, answer is basically 3.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The "Assume the variables are always positive and the first value is less than the second value" makes 80% of your code lines unnecessary. Even worse: returning 0 in the default case will make every result 0.

Comment: I read that. But my code is more complete and handles all -ve cases too. Where am I returning zero in the default case. I did not get that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a 1-liner:

```
public static int rangeProduct(int valueOne, int valueTwo) {
    return valueOne * (valueOne == valueTwo ? 1 : rangeProduct(++valueOne, valueTwo));
}
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/J4VL5D).